# 1tb hdd shows 1gb of memory instead

Tags: hard-drive

I just bought a new laptop - a Lenovo IdeaPad Y520-15.

It has a 128gb SSD and a 1tb HDD. The thing I noticed now is that HDD displays only 1gb of space.

I checked the HDD model (st1000lm035-1rk172) and indeed it should have 1 terabyte of space.

Is the HDD flawed or am I missing something after installing windows?

Screenshot of the hard drive:

[image]

Screenshot of the hard drive properties:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of Disk Management?

Comment: Ah I see, there was a lot of unallocated space. I just panicked seeing so little. Thanks for the help!

Comment: But it still shows only 976**MB** free, you appear to be missing 999,900MB or so. But that is only drive D:, the rest is probably unallocated / unpartitioned or hidden or something.

Comment: @Xen2050 if you read the comment directly above you, you'll see he already figured that out based on mtak's comment.

Comment: @LPChip The only screenshots didn't show the whole disk, so it seemed ambiguous, wasn't sure if PotatoOrgyLt got the right info. Cleared up now though, suppose mtak could post an answer (or whatever happens to unanswered questions, deleted eventually I suppose)

Answer (score 1):

It appeared that there was unallocated space on the drive itself. You mentioned that you found that out once you went to the Disk Management settings.

For those who find this answer through a search engine:
Right click the start menu and select Disk Management. If you are not on windows 8 or 10, then you can find Disk Management through Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management. (Or type `diskmgmt.msc` at a Run prompt or command prompt.)

From there, locate the disk and see if it has unallocated space. If so, right click the partition in front and choose expand.

*Written this answer so you can mark it as answered, and others know you no longer need help*